# Only Math SE won't stay open in Chrome/macOS, and other SE sites are fine. Is it just me?

Tags: discussion, support, google-chrome, mac

For a week or two, I've been having trouble with the Math SE main page even though other SE main pages are okay.

The two screenshots show what happens when I toggle between Space SE and Math SE. But as far as I can tell, it's *only* Math SE that errors out for me on my Google Chrome browser Version 118.0.5993.88 (Official Build) (x86_64) on macOS, using iPhone 4G wireless hotspot via USB.

**Note:** I've been using `math.stackexchange.com` to log in for a long time now (math only has four letters)

The Math SE *main* page displays properly for less than 1 second, and then the window goes black with "Aw Snap" + error 5.

*However*, specific question pages in Math SE show fine!

Am I the only one that has this behavior?

[image: SE sites other than Math SE load fine, but...] [image: ...but Math SE shows for less than a second then goes dark with "Aw Snap" and error code 5 in Chrome/macOS]

Click images for full size

**Update:**

*Interesting!* Math SE's main *question page* works fine, but when I delete `/questions` from the URL and hit return, *both* Math SE and Meta SE pages crash in Chrome's Incognito mode!

[image: This works] [image: but delete "/questions" and both tabs die!]

Click images for full size

Happened again circa 2023-11-15 23:32z. I was in a specific question in Math SE, then typed  math.stackexchange.com into bar and it "snapped" again.

I back arrowed to the question then forward arrowed back to the main site and it was ok.

[image: I was in a specific question in Math SE, then typed math.stackexchange.com into bar and it "snapped" again]

Comment: If you go to a tag page, does it also crash? If so, most likely the cause is the web socket code that check for new activity, which isn't active on the /questions page.

Comment: My first suspect would be LaTeX. Have you tried other sites that also support LaTeX? (I don't know which do, but others should be able to tell you.)

Comment: The [TeX - LaTeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) should...

Comment: @JonathanZ Space SE certainly loads MathJax as well,, yes, though Math SE tends to have it actually show up titles and the sidebar much more frequently, but why only the main page causes the problem and not the `/questions` page?

Comment: @ This_is_NOT_a_forum I don't know why "Click images for full size" needs capitalization (I think parenthesis would be better like the way you wrote "(we have italics and bold on this platform)") but if you are going to capitalize it then better add a period at the end to achieve your goal and maintain consistency, no?

Comment: I would suspect the combination of Chrome on MacOS. Firefox on MacOS is broken for me. MacOS 14.0 Sonoma, FF on continuous update.

Comment: Also MacBook Air Apple M1